# Responsive Video Intro Full Screen for web and Mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html

I have a client I'm working with that wants to have a full screen video intro on their site prior to redirecting them back to the homepage. They also want it cookie based so the user only sees the video once when they come back.

I have 2 issues so far:

1) I can't get the video to render on an iPad because onClick() does not work on the iPad. I've tried others but still can't figure it out.
2) They want a high quality video for the web and a lower quality to render for the ipad/iphone.

Here is what I currently have in the code for making the video load upon site load and making it accessible to all devices:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> onload="openVideo();">
 <div id="homepage-video" style="display:none;">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/splash-page-final.jpg" class="splash-image" />
    <video id="homepage-video-file" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
      preload="auto">  
     <source src="http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/files/somesite-intro-1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />  
     <source src="http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/files/somesite-intro.webm" type='video/webm' />  
     <source src="http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/files/somesite-intro.ogv" type='video/ogg' />  
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: It is 1999 again! For #2 sniff the user agent and server a different file when the page renders.

Comment: Thanks - that was not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

ua sniffing actually is a good choice for the different resolutions (as suggested above). what did you mean by onClick does not work pin the iPad??? sure it does!
did you try to trigger a click event automatically to start the video? that is blocked by iOS - autoplay will not work either. the user has to start the video manually